# Parsing one field to fill another field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP/MySQL and am working my way through the basics.

I have a MySQL database scwdb (that I moved from Access 2000 which my Windows 7 won't work with) with a table tblsplintersbowlinventory which has 2 fields:

fields and data:

```
txtProductBowlCode
data examples: OakSc07-001, MapleTi07-030, MapleTi07-034, BlackLimba07-002, AshSc07-017

txtProductPrimarySpecies
data examples: Oak, Maple, Maple, BlackLimba, Ash
```

In other words, I want to record just the species in the txtProductPrimarySpecies field.

I tried the following PHP script:

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxxx","zzzzzzz");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("scwdb", $con);

$species = 'Maple';
mysql_query("UPDATE tblsplintersbowlinventory WHERE txtProductBowlCode LIKE $species SET txtProductPrimarySpecies=$species%");
echo "done";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It seems to run, does not show an error and prints "done", but when I check the database I don't see any changes.

What am I missing?

This db has over 600 records, and I added this new txtProductPrimarySpecies field to make my searches easier while leaving the full code which has specific info on the bowl. There are several species that I need to do this to, so I plan on using a loop to run through a list of species.

## How would I code that loop to read a list of species?

OK, I found the way to make this work!

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","zzzzzzz");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("scwdb", $con);

$species = 'Maple';
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE tblsplintersbowlinventory SET txtProductPrimarySpecies = '$species' WHERE txtProductBowlCode LIKE '$species%'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsplintersbowlinventory WHERE txtProductBowlCode LIKE '$species%'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Bowl Code</th>
<th>Species</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['intProductID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['txtProductBowlCode'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['txtProductPrimarySpecies'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "done";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This worked, and I manually changed the $species value and ran it for each of the species of wood in the database...since this was a one time shot it made more sense not to use a list and loop through it - I was bound to miss one or two species anyway.

Comment: SET .. should be before WHERE .... you don't check for mysql errors - so you don't see any

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code... you mixed up the order of `SET` and `WHERE` as well as your arguments for `LIKE` and `SET`, didn't put string values into single quotes for starters. Also the [mysql_*](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) extensions have been deprecated.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: "Please, don't use mysql_* functions to write new code."...interesting, since I copied the code from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp last night...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `set without %` come before `where with %`. Also I think your parameter should be wrapped with a quote as it is string type.

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE tblsplintersbowlinventory 
                SET txtProductPrimarySpecies='$species' 
                WHERE txtProductBowlCode LIKE 'CONCAT($species, '%')'");
```

Comment: I tried this code, still doesn't work...I see on another question that the CONCAT command means "concat is concatenation, or joining the results from two columns" - I don't think that's what I am trying to do...what I wanted to do was pull out the species (maple) and drop the Ti07-030 and set the txtProductPrimarySpecies field to Maple.

Comment: No error noted, it simply runs and prints 'done'. When I look at the database (after renewing it) there is no change - the field is empty.

Comment: @Stephen What error are you getting now? CONCAT is appending '%` to you param `$species`. I didn't understand why you were using same param in set and where. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Stephen what is the current value and what are you trying to update? I will update the query.

Comment: I set $species = Maple before the query. I use the WHERE to look for the txtProductBowlCode field with Maple and then put the data Maple in the txtProductPrimarySpeciesfield. As I said, I get no error message, it just runs to the end and prints the word Done at the end.

Comment: OK, I just realized what the 'CONCAT($species, '%')' does...it adds % to the end of $species...I could add the % when I define $species...

Comment: @Stephen: Please let me know, once you are back. We will chat and try to fix your issue.